# Optimize the distribition of a dataset over 4 quadrants

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to optimise the distribition of a number of records over four 
quadrants.

As a example I use this dataset

```
data={{525.48,37.02},{525.2,36.86},{528.44,36.995},{533.27,36.795},{534.31,36.59},{536.26,36.53},{535.66,36.52},{534.24,36.515},{534.71,36.5},{535.41,36.},{535.76,35.74},{529.06,34.98},{524.52,34.545},{526.92,34.935},{527.85,35.145},{528.17,35.48},{527.87,35.64},{527.46,35.6},{528.03,35.74},{527.73,35.865},{525.71,35.935},{524.07,36.},{527.03,36.285},{526.74,36.35},{524.44,36.065},{521.71,35.82},{523.1,35.8},{523.55,35.48},{527.3,35.8},{521.89,35.17},{523.39,35.54},{521.71,35.55},{518.75,35.36},{520.67,36.175},{525.87,36.8},{520.88,36.385},{520.48,36.53},{519.39,36.695},{519.5,36.16},{520.62,36.11},{518.73,35.445},{516.39,35.455},{508.53,34.775},{507.15,34.86},{513.12,35.015},{511.73,34.905},{511.35,35.2},{509.94,35.1},{509.92,35.1},{512.05,35.37},{510.99,35.195},{516.59,35.695},{519.11,35.475},{521.07,35.66},{521.5,35.815},{518.17,35.705},{524.25,35.92},{526.29,35.735},{522.22,35.35},{521.65,35.03},{524.69,35.41},{527.72,36.05},{530.35,37.005},{525.53,36.61},{525.44,36.9},{527.48,36.605},{525.3,36.265},{525.57,35.675},{529.09,37.205},{531.41,37.49},{532.68,37.595},{528.21,37.43},{523.63,37.25},{516.97,36.76},{521.1,37.005},{522.67,36.955},{525.89,37.36},{523.71,37.275},{519.64,37.34},{516.71,37.19},{521.87,37.665},{519.36,37.67},{519.1,37.485},{517.42,37.4},{514.76,36.99},{510.03,36.655},{513.01,37.055},{516.04,37.375},{518.18,37.555},{516.27,37.225},{515.46,37.58},{516.47,37.5},{518.83,37.915},{518.82,38.195},{523.96,38.435},{526.58,38.82},{528.69,39.115},{529.34,39.47},{526.78,39.575},{529.31,39.91},{528.66,39.82},{528.66,39.65},{528.47,39.77},{528.03,39.81},{527.78,39.675},{528.5,39.88},{531.09,39.84},{533.39,40.405},{537.06,40.905},{541.04,41.29},{542.25,41.305},{541.65,41.755},{542.88,41.53},{539.9,41.28},{541.19,41.205},{541.14,41.265},{541.76,41.33},{542.84,41.235},{546.21,41.29},{546.67,41.265},{546.62,41.155},{547.68,41.425},{544.56,41.215},{544.63,41.405},{545.96,41.375},{543.67,41.3},{541.27,41.58},{547.67,41.965},{549.44,42.115},{549.46,41.995},{553.38,42.345},{554.49,42.445},{553.83,42.63},{555.15,43.13},{555.22,42.635},{553.8,42.67},{554.77,42.21},{550.37,41.67},{547.32,41.64},{545.43,41.165},{541.73,41.545},{538.49,41.27},{539.19,41.73},{536.62,41.385},{539.71,41.85},{541.82,41.955},{540.02,41.64},{541.35,41.73},{540.63,41.695},{538.09,41.535},{543.59,42.47},{541.42,42.605},{540.11,42.9},{535.57,42.3},{541.54,43.2},{543.08,43.15},{542.77,43.035},{544.51,43.36},{547.22,43.535},{548.41,43.26},{552.87,42.915},{550.56,42.74},{547.47,42.555},{548.67,42.33},{553.29,42.935},{552.03,42.565},{547.38,42.265},{549.39,42.32},{548.48,42.43},{548.48,42.43},{548.6,42.49},{548.6,42.49},{547.06,42.465},{544.58,42.34},{544.79,42.17},{544.79,42.17},{549.34,42.8},{554.06,43.5},{558.16,44.07},{560.89,44.31},{563.04,44.83},{560.44,44.56},{558.89,44.41},{561.1,44.27},{561.06,44.33},{561.18,44.29},{563.28,44.17},{566.49,44.},{569.3,44.64},{570.82,43.97},{570.6,43.93},{566.04,43.88},{565.07,43.31},{566.79,43.5},{566.06,43.13},{561.,43.22},{560.52,43.97},{556.87,43.24},{550.08,42.46},{542.65,41.53},{526.18,40.2},{536.36,41.29},{526.12,40.26},{518.33,39.61},{524.1,39.84},{520.57,39.5},{525.64,39.64},{527.57,40.33},{532.27,40.69},{528.76,40.56},{532.93,41.27},{533.95,41.29},{532.64,41.27},{534.09,41.12},{538.31,41.42},{537.83,41.62},{535.58,41.27},{529.59,39.98},{518.72,39.06},{526.51,40.76},{528.36,41.38},{530.71,42.43},{535.22,43.4},{537.14,43.46},{538.43,44.},{532.52,43.88},{530.97,43.74},{533.3,43.83},{533.3,43.64},{533.3,43.64},{533.3,43.64},{533.3,43.64},{521.45,42.2},{521.45,41.77},{518.75,41.13},{525.76,41.52},{527.,41.15},{529.52,41.36},{529.52,41.36},{528.48,40.83},{528.48,40.83},{526.19,40.26},{540.49,41.26},{539.29,41.54},{539.9,41.25},{545.25,41.88},{544.5,41.39},{547.9,41.4},{548.05,41.14},{546.62,41.36},{551.32,41.78},{553.35,41.74},{551.31,41.44},{550.38,40.76},{554.25,41.18},{556.44,41.05},{551.73,40.62},{554.41,41.13},{554.94,40.9},{555.73,40.84},{555.86,41.06},{555.86,41.06},{551.73,40.61},{555.7,41.12},{557.86,41.2},{558.51,41.54},{561.51,41.46},{562.18,41.59},{562.27,41.36},{563.52,41.43},{564.49,41.85},{565.13,42.14},{568.96,41.7},{567.03,41.81},{570.07,42.44},{572.05,42.85},{565.07,42.64},{561.62,42.86},{562.77,43.39},{559.84,43.36},{554.77,42.5},{557.6,42.24},{552.85,41.86}}
```

In this example I use two 'hardcoded' conditions (a en b):

```
a = 50;
b = 50;

q1 = Select[
   data, #[[1]] < 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]] && #[[2]] < 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]] & ];
q2 = Select[
   data, #[[1]] < 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]] && #[[2]] > 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]] & ];
q3 = Select[
   data, #[[1]] > 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]] && #[[2]] < 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]] & ];
q4 = Select[
   data, #[[1]] > 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]] && #[[2]] > 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]] & ];
{Length[q1], Length[q2], Length[q3], Length[q4]}
dataLP = ListPlot[{q1, q2, q3, q4}, 
  GridLines -> {{Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]]}, {Max[
      Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]]}}
  , Epilog -> {
    Inset[Text[Style["Q4", 14]], {Center, Center}]
    , Inset[Text[Style["Q2", 14]], {510, Center}]
    , Inset[Text[Style["Q3", 14]], {540, 35}]
    , Inset[Text[Style["Q1", 14]], {510, 35}]}];
```

[image]

My goal is to make a distribution of the data (over 4 segments) based on a parameter/percentage

In segment 1 I want to have approximately 10% of al the records. The same I want for the segments 2 en 3. So in Segmenbt 4 I get approximately 70% of all the records. In a another example I would like to work with e another distributioin, for example 20%, 20%, 20% and 40%

One way top do it is to calculate all possibilities like:

```
Table[
 q1 = Select[
   data, #[[1]] < 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]] && #[[2]] < 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]] & ];
 q2 = Select[
   data, #[[1]] < 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]] && #[[2]] > 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]] & ];
 q3 = Select[
   data, #[[1]] > 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]] && #[[2]] < 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]] & ];
 q4 = Select[
   data, #[[1]] > 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 1]]], a]] && #[[2]] > 
      Max[Take[NumericalSort[data[[All, 2]]], b]] & ];
 {Length[q1], Length[q2], Length[q3], Length[q4]}, {a, 1, 200}, {b, 1, 
  200}];
```

But this approach takes a lot of time. I'm looking for a smarter calculation. Who has a suggestion?

Comment: I don't think you can get there from here.  You can certainly select a point $(x_0,y_0)$ to obtain a desired proportion in $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ and a desired proportion in $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ but you can't (usually) get all 4 desired proportions.  Also (to further show my confusion), I'm not following what is being optimized.

Comment: You can also pick the proportions in say $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ but that completely determines the proportions in $Q_3$ and $Q_4$.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially after picking any the two proportions for neighboring cells, the remaining two proportions are already fully determined.  If you desire certain proportions for $Q_1$ and $Q_4$ or $Q_2$ and $Q_3$ (i.e., diagonal quadrants), then depending on the dataset, you might not be able to achieve those proportions.

Here's one way to obtain desired proportions when specifying the proportions for $Q_1$ and $Q_2$:

```
f[p1_, p2_] := Module[{x0, y0, q, q1, q2, q3, q4, xLeft, xRight, yLower, yUpper},

  (* Determine the point that will give those two proportions *)
  x0 = Quantile[data[[All, 1]], p1 + p2];
  y0 = Quantile[Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 &][[All, 2]], p1/(p1 + p2)];

  (* Assign the points to each quadrant *)
  q1 = Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
  q2 = Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];
  q3 = Select[data, #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
  q4 = Select[data, #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];

  (* Find proportions in each quadrant *)
  proportions = N[Length[#] & /@ {q1, q2, q3, q4}/Length[data]];

  (* Determine locations on the plot for placing the proportions *)
  xLeft = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]] + Min[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]])/2;
  xRight = (Max[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]] + Min[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]])/2;
  yLower = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]] + Min[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]])/2;
  yUpper = (Max[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]] + Min[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]])/2;

  (* Show results *)
  q = Select[{q1, q2, q3, q4}, # != {} &];
  Show[ListPlot[q, ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> {
      Inset[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[1]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 36], {xLeft, yLower}],
      Inset[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[2]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 36], {xLeft, yUpper}],
      Inset[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[3]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 36], {xRight, yLower}],
      Inset[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[4]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 36], {xRight, yUpper}]}],
   ListPlot[{{{x0, Min[data[[All, 2]]]}, {x0, Max[data[[All, 2]]]}},
     {{Min[data[[All, 1]]], y0}, {Max[data[[All, 1]]], y0}}},
    Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black]
   ]]

f[0.1, 0.2]
```

[image: Q1 0.1 and Q2 0.2]

```
f[0.4, 0.5]
```

[image: Q1 0.4 and Q2 0.5]

If by "optimizing" you mean that you want to pick a point $(x_0,y_0)$ that will divide the points into the 4 quadrants with proportions "close" to a desired set of proportions, then you'll need to specify the desired measure of closeness *and* what level of closeness is adequate.  (Just having something as close as it can be with respect to some measure doesn't mean that the "fit" is adequate.)

Comment: Replicating your Code above with only 6 data points with names `lst={aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, gg}`, I wanted to label the data points with `lst` (Tooltip), but I could not do it. I tried: `groupeddata = GatherBy[Thread[{x0, y0} ->lst], Last]` and `ListPlot[groupeddata]`. Can you give me an idea about how to do it?