# How to use Manipulate to place `Tooltip` for each data point on a ListPlot with a varying Linear Regression line

Tags: fitting, code-request, tooltip

I want to build on an already developed `Code` given in:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183401/60365

For easy implementation, I applied it to a sample of 10 observations. Given:

```
data = {{525.48, 37.02}, {525.2, 36.86}, {528.44, 36.995}, 
        {533.27, 36.795}, {534.31, 36.59}, {536.26, 36.53}, 
        {535.66, 36.52}, {534.24, 36.515}, {534.71, 36.5}, 
        {535.41, 36}};

dataLabels = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "gg", "hh", "kk", "nn", "mm"};
```

Implement:

```
f[p1_, p2_] := Module[{x0, y0, q, q1, q2, q3, q4, xLeft, xRight, yLower, yUpper}, (*Determine the point that will give those two proportions*)
x0 = Quantile[data[[All, 1]], p1 + p2];
y0 = Quantile[Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 &][[All, 2]], p1/(p1 + p2)];

(*Assign the points to each quadrant*)
q1 = Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
q2 = Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];
q3 = Select[data, #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
q4 = Select[data, #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];

(*Find proportions in each quadrant*)
proportions = N[Length[#] & /@ {q1, q2, q3, q4}/Length[data]];

(*Determine locations on the plot for placing the proportions*)
xLeft = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]] + 
  Min[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]])/2;
xRight = (Max[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]] + 
  Min[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]])/2;
yLower = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]] + 
  Min[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]])/2;
yUpper = (Max[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]] + 
  Min[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]])/2;

(*Show results*)
q = Select[{q1, q2, q3, q4}, # != {} &];
Show[ListPlot[q, ImageSize -> Large, 
Epilog -> {Inset[
   Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[1]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 
    36], {xLeft, yLower}], 
  Inset[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[2]], {10, 3}]], 
    Bold, 36], {xLeft, yUpper}], 
  Inset[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[3]], {10, 3}]], 
    Bold, 36], {xRight, yLower}], 
  Inset[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[4]], {10, 3}]], 
    Bold, 36], {xRight, yUpper}]}], 
 ListPlot[{{{x0, Min[data[[All, 2]]]}, {x0, 
   Max[data[[All, 2]]]}}, {{Min[data[[All, 1]]], 
   y0}, {Max[data[[All, 1]]], y0}}}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black]]]
```

The above `Code` works as expected. I wanted to add two more features to the existing `Code`:

1. How can I add a linear or nonlinear regression line on top of the 4-quadrant figure?
2. How can I label each observation on the `ListPlot` using `Tooltip` with `dataLabels`?

Thank you.

**CODE REVISED**

```
ClearAll[typeTFP, measureTFP, proportions, poly, dataLabels];
typeTFP = {data, datagr1, datagr};
measureTFP = {"TFP Distance", "TFP Growth   Rate Distance", "TFP Growth Rate Distance DWA"};

Manipulate[
  Module[
   {x0, y0, q, q1, q2, q3, q4, xLeft, xRight, yLower, yUpper},

(*Determine the point that will give selected two proportions*)
 x0 = Quantile[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear][[All, 1]], 
 p1 + p2];   (*p1 denotes the proportion for Q1, and p2, the proportion for Q2*)
 y0 = Quantile[
  Select[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear], #[[1]] <= x0 &][[All,2]], p1/(p1 + p2)];

(*Assign the points to each quadrant*)
 q1 = Select[
   typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear], #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
 q2 = Select[
   typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear], #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];
 q3 = Select[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear], #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
 q4 = Select[
   typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear], #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];

 (*Find proportions in each quadrant*)
 proportions = 
   N[Length[#] & /@ {q1, q2, q3, q4}/
 Length[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear]]];

 (*Determine locations on the plot for placing the proportions*)
 xLeft = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]] + Min[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]])/2;  (* Exo.factor left of the vertical line on X-axis *)
 xRight = (Max[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]] + Min[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]])/2;   (* Exo. factor right of the vertical line on X-axis *)
 yLower = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]] + Min[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]])/2;  (*TFPdist below the horizontal line on Y-axis *)
 yUpper = (Max[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]] + Min[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]])/2;  (*TFPdist above the horizontal line on Y-axis *)

 (*Show results*)
 q = Select[{q1, q2, q3, q4}, # != {} &];

 poly[x] := 
   With[{n = 2}, NonlinearModelFit[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear], Total@Table[a[k] x^k, {k, 0, n}], a /@ Range[0, n], x] //Normal];
 dataLabels[factor, initYear] = 
  StringTake[dataCountry[factor,initYear]   // Flatten, 3];

 Show[ListPlot[q /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :>Callout[{x, y}, Style[dataLabels[factor, initYear][[Position[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear], {x, y}][[1,1]]]], 10]],
 ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {vars[[factor]], measureTFP[[type]]}), Prolog -> {(*Move lines and text to Prolog so they are not on top of the data*) 
Black, Text[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[1]], {10, 2}]], 
Bold, 18], {xLeft, yLower}],     Text[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[2]], {10, 2}]], 
Bold,16], {xLeft, yUpper}],    Text[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[3]], {10, 2}]], 
Bold, 16], {xRight, yLower}],     Text[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[4]], {10, 2}]], 
Bold, 16], {xRight, yUpper}],      Line[{{x0, Min[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear][[All, 2]]]}, {x0, Max[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear][[All, 2]]]}}], 
Line[{{Min[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear][[All, 1]]], y0}, {Max[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear][[All, 1]]], y0}}]}], 
Plot[poly[xp], {xp,       Min[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear][[All, 1]]], Max[typeTFP[[type]][factor, initYear][[All, 1]]]}]]],

Spacer[40],
Delimiter, Style["Parameters for TFP Distance Network", Bold, Medium],
{{initYear, 1, "Choose an initial period for TFP: "},   Thread[Range[Length[years] - 1] ->Take[years, 10]], ControlType -> PopupMenu}, 
{{type, 1, "Choose the type of TFP measure: "}, Thread[Range[Length[measureTFP]] -> measureTFP], ControlType -> PopupMenu},
{{factor, 14, "Choose an exogenous factor:"},  Thread[Range[Length[vars]] -> vars], ControlType -> PopupMenu}, 
{{p1, 0.20, "Choose a proportion for TFP_Lower: "}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{p2, 0.35, "Choose a proportion for TFP_Upper: "}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", Style["Four Quadrants: TFP Measure versus Exogenous Factor", Larger, Bold, Black]}}
```

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{525.48, 37.02}, {525.2, 36.86}, {528.44, 36.995}, {533.27, 
    36.795}, {534.31, 36.59}, {536.26, 36.53}, {535.66, 36.52}, {534.24, 
    36.515}, {534.71, 36.5}, {535.41, 36}};
```

For a quadratic fit

```
poly[x_] = With[{n = 2}, NonlinearModelFit[data,
    Total@Table[a[k] x^k, {k, 0, n}],
    a /@ Range[0, n], x] // Normal]

(* -2233.98 + 8.61496 x - 0.00817032 x^2 *)

dataLabels = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "gg", "hh", "kk", "nn", "mm"};
```

Modified `Module`

```
f[p1_, p2_] := 
 Module[{x0, y0, q, q1, q2, q3, q4, xLeft, xRight, yLower, yUpper},
  (*Determine the point that will give those two proportions*)
  x0 = Quantile[data[[All, 1]], p1 + p2];
  y0 = Quantile[Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 &][[All, 2]], p1/(p1 + p2)];
  (*Assign the points to each quadrant*)
  q1 = Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
  q2 = Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];
  q3 = Select[data, #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
  q4 = Select[data, #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];
  (*Find proportions in each quadrant*)
  proportions =
   N[Length[#] & /@ {q1, q2, q3, q4}/Length[data]];
  (*Determine locations on the plot for placing the proportions*)
  xLeft = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]] +
      Min[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]])/2;
  xRight = (Max[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]] +
      Min[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]])/2;
  yLower = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]] +
      Min[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]])/2;
  yUpper = (Max[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]] +
      Min[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]])/2;
  (*Show results*)
  q = Select[{q1, q2, q3, q4}, # != {} &];
  Show[
   ListPlot[q /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :>
      Tooltip[{x, y}, Style[dataLabels[[Position[data, {x, y}][[1, 1]]]], 24]],
    ImageSize -> Large,
    Prolog -> {
      (* Move lines and text to Prolog so they are not on top of the data *)
           Gray,
      Text[
       Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[1]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 36],
       {xLeft, yLower}],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[2]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 36],
       {xLeft, yUpper}],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[3]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 36],
       {xRight, yLower}],
      Text[
       Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[4]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 36],
       {xRight, yUpper}],
      Line[{{x0, Min[data[[All, 2]]]},
        {x0, Max[data[[All, 2]]]}}],
      Line[{{Min[data[[All, 1]]], y0},
        {Max[data[[All, 1]]], y0}}]}],
   Plot[poly[xp], {xp, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]]]
```

Plots

```
f[0.2, 0.3]
```

[image]

Comment: It is very nice. Is it possible to use `Tooltip` to give a label for each observation? Currently, when I move the cursor on top of the observation point, I see the label attached to it. I would like to see the labels permanently written next to the plots. Thanks.

Comment: Then you don't want a `Tooltip`. Change `Tooltip` to `Callout`.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my mistake in naming. Thanks for the code. It works as I wanted.

Comment: In plotting nonlinear regression line, I face a problem. In the example I gave above, `data` is given outside of `Module` but in my real case, `data` is generated within `Module` using `Manipulate`. Even if I give numeric max and min values for `xp` in `Plot[poly[xp]...]` I cannot see the regression line. The only difference between my example case and the actual case is the location of `data`. Do you think that it is the reason for not being able to see the regression line?

Comment: Did you move the definition of `poly` inside the `Module`? Without seeing your code I can only guess. Suggest that you post a new question with the minimum amount of data and code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I edited the question with the revised `Code` without data because the data set is very large. But I should indicate that this `Code` works very fine and I have no problem, except it does not show the Regression line estimated by `poly[x]`, which is placed inside `Module` which is further inside `Manipulate`. I wonder if I make a programming problem as I get no data error whatsoever. Thanks.

Comment: We cannot execute the code without a representative sample of data. We do not need all of the data but we need some to see how it is structured and to be able to determine why the code is apparently not handling it as intended. Also, by not initiating a new question you are severely limiting the number of people who are likely to see this.

Comment: I will write a separate question as you indicated. I hope we can solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: In fact, when I was preparing a new question, I tried your code without `Module` but `Manipulate`. Then your code worked as I wanted to. I will post the answer just to show the difference between your and the one I revised. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a revision of @Bob Hanlon's code above with two adjustments: the use of `Callout` instead of `Tooltip` and the use of `Manipulate` instead of `Module`. One can then play with different polynomial degrees denoted by `n` as a control.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[11];
data = RandomReal[{0, 300}, {40, 2}];
Manipulate[

(*Determine the point that will give those two proportions*)
x0 = Quantile[data[[All, 1]], p1 + p2];
y0 = Quantile[Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 &][[All, 2]], p1/(p1 + p2)];

(*Assign the points to each quadrant*)
q1 = Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
q2 = Select[data, #[[1]] <= x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];
q3 = Select[data, #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] <= y0 &];
q4 = Select[data, #[[1]] > x0 && #[[2]] > y0 &];

(*Find proportions in each quadrant*)
proportions = N[Length[#] & /@ {q1, q2, q3,q4}/Length[data]];

(*Determine locations on the plot for placing the proportions*)
xLeft = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]] +     
   Min[Join[q1[[All, 1]], q2[[All, 1]]]])/2;
xRight = (Max[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]] + 
   Min[Join[q3[[All, 1]], q4[[All, 1]]]])/2;
yLower = (Max[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]] + 
   Min[Join[q1[[All, 2]], q3[[All, 2]]]])/2;
yUpper = (Max[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]] + 
   Min[Join[q2[[All, 2]], q4[[All, 2]]]])/2;

(*Show results*)
q = Select[{q1, q2, q3, q4}, # != {} &];

poly[x_] = 
NonlinearModelFit[data, Total@Table[a[k] x^k, {k, 0, n}], a /@ Range[0, n], x] // Normal; 
dataLabels = {"aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "gg", "hh", "kk", "nn", "mm", "aa1", "bb1", "cc1", "dd1", "ee1", "gg1", "hh1", "kk1", "nn1", "mm1", "aa2", bb2", "cc2", "dd2", "ee2", "gg2", "hh2", "kk2", "nn2", mm2", "aa3", "bb3", "cc3", "dd3", "ee3", "gg3", "hh3", "kk3", "nn3", "mm3"};

 Show[
  ListPlot[
   q /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :>Callout[{x, y}, Style[dataLabels[[Position[data, {x, y}][[1, 1]]]], 12]], ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"Fertility", "TFP measure"}), Prolog -> {(*Move lines and text to Prolog so they are not on top of the data*)
Black, 
 Text[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[1]], {10, 3}]], Bold,16], {xLeft, yLower}],
 Text[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[2]], {10, 3}]], Bold, 16], {xLeft, yUpper}],
 Text[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[3]], {10, 3}]], Bold,16], {xRight, yLower}],
 Text[Style[ToString[NumberForm[proportions[[4]], {10, 3}]], Bold,16], {xRight, yUpper}],
 Line[{{x0, Min[data[[All, 2]]]}, {x0, Max[data[[All, 2]]]}}], 
 Line[{{Min[data[[All, 1]]], y0}, {Max[data[[All, 1]]], y0}}]}], Plot[poly[xp], {xp, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]],
{{n, 2, "Choose a polynomial degree: "}, 1, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{p1, 0.20, "Choose a Low-Low proportion: "}, 0, 
  1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
{{p2, 0.35, "Choose a Low-Up proportion: "}, 0, 1, 
  .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"",Style["Four Quadrants: TFP Measure versus Fertility", Larger,Bold, Black]}}]
```

Here is the final output:
[image]